# Does "INSERT INTO ... SELECT" update new inserted records on selected table?

Tags: database, postgresql, select, insert

For example you got the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_A (id, item) SELECT id, item FROM table_B
```

Assume that the table_B has millions of records, enough to take several minutes inserting. What would happen if during insertion, new records are inserted into the "table_B".

Are these records also inserted in the "table_A"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much context I would assume you need to look into how the application that does the "one off" inserts, subsequent to your major insert from table-b ---> table-a, handles table locks.

With locking setup correctly you should not have any issues losing data.

[PostgreSQL Table Locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-lock.html)

Comment: I was not aware of table locking in postgresql, will look into it, Thanks you!

Comment: @Jackknife - If this proved helpful, please consider marking it as the answer.  Thanks.